# Python input ranges and types of input

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do i get it to not keep repeating after a sucessfull trial

```
while age == "": #make it only except numbers so it wont give an error
    age = input("How old are you " + name + "? ")
    if age.isdigit() == False: 
        print("Only digits are allowed!")
        age = ""
    if age not in range(0,99):
        print ("Age must be between 0,90!")
        age = ""
```

Comment: `age` is a string, `range` objects are sequences of `int` objects, they will never contain a `str` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert the input to int to check it's value:

```
while age == "":  # make it only except numbers so it wont give an error
    age = input("How old are you " + name + "? ")
    if not age.isdigit():
        print("Only digits are allowed!")
        age = ""
    elif int(age) not in range(0, 99):
        print("Age must be between 0,99!")
        age = ""
```

Answer (score -1):

Your variable "age" is a string - that's what the "input" function returns.  Later you check to see if it's in the range (0, 90), but the "range" function returns a sequence of integers.  So "age" - a string - is NEVER in the sequence.

Here is one way to fix it:

```
while age == "": #make it only except numbers so it wont give an error
    age = input("How old are you " + name + "? ")
    if age.isdigit() == False: 
        print("Only digits are allowed!")
        age = ""
    if int(age) not in range(0,99):
        print ("Age must be between 0,90!")
        age = ""
```